# Search multiple strings

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists of strings - `x` and `y`. `x` is the header from different web pages (are delimited by hyphen):

```
x = [  
     'ABC-12345-TTTT-MMMM-00000-FINSA1',
     'ABC-0000-KKKK-MMMM-00000-FINSA2' ,
     'ABC-3987-TKTKT-JJJJ-00000-FINSA1',
     'ABC-9990-TTTT-MMMM-00000-FINSA4' ,
     'ABC-5990-NNNN-MUUUT-00000-FINSA2'
     ]
```

`y` is the carrier code:

```
y = ['FINSA1','FINSA2']
```

I want to match all strings in `y` (for all carrier codes) to all strings in `x` (all Headers). If match is found, then append `'-X1'` at the end of each matched `x`.

The `append` part is easy, but I am not able to match each string in `y`.

I tried using the following:

1. `if (x.find(y) != -1):` (this only returns the last value `FINSA2`)
2. `name = [1 for i in x if subs in y]` - doesn't work

Comment: Tomerikoo - first of all thank you so much for formatting the question. I tried the following - 
x  = ['header1' , 'header2', 'header3,'header4',......]
y = ['carriercode1','carriercode2','carriercode3'........]
for name in x:
       if any(name in x for carriercode in y):
       print(x)
i only get the headers for FINSA2 (last carrier code). Let me know if I'm doing it wrong

Comment: you are checking the obvious: `for name in x: if any(name in x ...)`. You need to do: `for name in x: if any(carriercode in name for carriercode in y): print(name)`

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `any` in a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) in a list comprehension should to the trick:

```
In [1]: x = [   
   ...:      'ABC-12345-TTTT-MMMM-00000-FINSA1', 
   ...:      'ABC-0000-KKKK-MMMM-00000-FINSA2' , 
   ...:      'ABC-3987-TKTKT-JJJJ-00000-FINSA1', 
   ...:      'ABC-9990-TTTT-MMMM-00000-FINSA4' , 
   ...:      'ABC-5990-NNNN-MUUUT-00000-FINSA2' 
   ...:      ] 
   ...: 

In [2]: y = ['FINSA1','FINSA2']

In [3]: [i+'-X1' if any(t in i for t in y) else i for i in x]
Out[3]: 
['ABC-12345-TTTT-MMMM-00000-FINSA1-X1',
 'ABC-0000-KKKK-MMMM-00000-FINSA2-X1',
 'ABC-3987-TKTKT-JJJJ-00000-FINSA1-X1',
 'ABC-9990-TTTT-MMMM-00000-FINSA4',
 'ABC-5990-NNNN-MUUUT-00000-FINSA2-X1']
```

Let's break this down. The outer expression is a list comprehension over `x`, with `i` representing individual elements of `x`. `t in i for t in y` is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), which is a kind of iterable. The `any` function takes an iterable and produces `True` if any of the values in the iterator are true. So if any of the strings in `y` are in `i`, `any` returns `True`. In that case, `-X1` is appended to `i`.